How to handle concurrency issues with SQL Server?
I am having issues in my .NET 6 project using SQL Server and Entity Framework. I have my application deployed on Kubernetes, so there are 3 pods. I have multiple users attempting to fetch the next available 'Order' record from the database (Username = null, Status = 'Available'). When a user fetches the next Order, they get their username assigned to the Order record, and then the record is updated using await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync() to reflect that assignment. I want every user to have a unique Order to review, but some users are getting the same Order record, causing concurrency issues.
I already have the save in a Try/Catch block that is catching DbUpdateConcurrencyException, which seems to prevent most concurrency problems. However, there are still a few operations that do not get caught and succeed with a double update operation. These operations are happening at the same exact time (sub .2 seconds), and on different pods.
Screenshot of logs
var nextAvailableOrder = await _dbContext.Orders
      .Where(o => o.Status == OrderStatus.Available && o.Username == null)
      .OrderByDescending(o => o.Type)
      .ThenBy(o => o.DateOfService)
      .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);

if (nextAvailableOrder == null)
{
    return null;
}
try
{
    // Assign new user and transition Order to new status
    // Order.Username = request.Username
    // Order.Status = 'In Progress'
    _stateEngine.MoveNext(nextAvailableOrder, OrderAction.GetNext, request.Username);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

    return nextAvailableOrder;
}
                
   // Handle concurrency issues
   catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
{
// Retry logic
}

I am using the Username field on the Order record as a concurrency token, but the issue of parallel updates still persists. Any suggestions would be welcome.

You don't show how you get the nextAvailableOrder, you must ensure that no one else gets the nextAvailableOrder.  We use a Sequence but there are other ways depending how you are getting that value.

There are several things I would point out about this: first _dbContext "suggests" that you're injecting your db context into a singleton as a private readonly variable.  If you are, you should instead inject a scoped db context using the service scope factory.  Secondly, the fact that there's data corruption like this suggests that you may be sharing EF coupled objects in the rest of your app instead of having a repository design and sharing decoupled ef shared models above the domain layer.  It's harder to see the exact issue though without the code.

I added the code that fetches the next available order. dbContext is initialized using services.AddDbContext in the ServiceCollectionsExtensions.

What's the concurrency token in Order? In other words, did you configure optimistic concurrency correctly?

You have an issue in that you're making 2 separate calls to SQL, one to find the next item, and another to update the Username/Status if it is valid. You need to make this into a single SQL transaction, ideally with proper locking.
My recommendation would be to either use a Stored Procedure which will return the next available Order and update the Status at the same time.
Or, perform the update using ExecuteUpdate, and then select the record afterward, as shown here.
var key = Guid.NewGuid();
var rowsUpdated = _dbContext.Orders
      .Where(o => o.Status == OrderStatus.Available && o.Username == null)
      .OrderByDescending(o => o.Type)
      .ThenBy(o => o.DateOfService)
      .Take(1) // untested, but I don't see why it shouldn't work since it's an IQueryable
      .ExecuteUpdate(setters => setters
          .SetProperty(o => o.Username, request.Username)
          .SetProperty(o => o.Status, OrderStatus.Available)
          .SetProperty(o => o.SomeKey, key.toString()) // need to add SomeKey to model
       );

if (rowsUpdated == 1){
    var nextOrder = _dbContext.Orders
        .FirstOrDefault(o => o.SomeKey == key.toString());
}

Relevant Documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/execute-insert-update-delete#executeupdate
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations#using-isolation-levels-for-concurrency-control
